# How to set sql_safe_updates via my.cnf?

Tags: mariadb

I'm running

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.10-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

How can I set the system variable [`sql_safe_updates`](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/all/system-variables/sql_safe_updates/) via my.cnf? I want it to always be on.

Comment: Note this is just showing the client version. For the server version `SELECT VERSION()`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can set it in the `[mysqld]` block. e.g.

```
[mysqld]
sql_safe_updates        = 1
```

Test it's set after you connect:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_safe_updates';
```

Comment: Obviously requires a MariaDB server restart - `sudo systemctl restart mariadb` or similar.

Comment: Not sure why you included `sql_mode` in the answer. A better test is `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_safe_updates` to ensure it isn't just set for the session.

Comment: @danblack Just to show it alongside another var in the same block, one that will also make your queries safer. Removed for brevity, and fixed the "show" query per your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: 'sql_safe_updates = 1' did not work for me on MariaDb when I tried adding it to a [client] section of .my.cnf. However, 'safe_updates = 1' did.